# Foundry invariant tests: targetArtifact not seemed to be working

Tags: foundry, fuzz-test, invariant-test

I'm working on a project that is deployed behind a proxy, and looking to do invariant tests with it in foundry.

My setup in my invariant test looks as such:

```js
function setUp() public {
        initializerData = abi.encodeWithSignature(
            "initialize(string,string,uint256,uint256,(address,uint256)[],uint256)",
            tokenName,
            tokenSymbol,
            compositionTolerance,
            compositionEnforcementThreshold,
            fees,
            withdrawlFee
        );
        implementation = new Logic();
        implProxy = new ERC1967Proxy(address(implementation), initializerData);
        myContract = MyContract(address(implProxy));
        targetContract(address(myContract));
        targetArtifact("MyContract");
        excludeArtifact("ERC1967Proxy");
    }
```

And an invariant test:

```js
    function invariant_getDepositRoomDoesntHold() public {
        assert(myContract.accessed() == false);
    }
```

However, running `RUST_LOG=trace forge test -vvvvv` results in:

```
2023-02-14T16:58:39.271000Z ERROR contract{name=test/MyContractTest.t.MyContractTest}: forge::multi_runner: error=No contracts to fuzz.
```

I'm not sure how it's not finding any contracts to test, I clearly am adding one with:

```
targetContract(address(myContract));
targetArtifact("MyContract");
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. It turns out they [renamed](https://github.com/foundry-rs/forge-std/commit/b4f121555729b3afb3c5ffccb62ff4b6e2818fd3) `InvariantTest`  to `StdInvariant`. So, you have to import `StdInvariant` contract and extend your test contract for property-based fuzzing. For example:

```js
pragma solidity ^0.8.13;

import {Test} from "forge-std/Test.sol";
import {StdInvariant} from "forge-std/StdInvariant.sol";
import {WETH9} from "../src/WETH9.sol";

contract WETH9Invariants is StdInvariant, Test {
    WETH9 public weth;

    function setUp() public {
        weth = new WETH9();
    }

    function invariant_badInvariantThisShouldFail() public {
        assertEq(1, weth.totalSupply());
    }
}
```

And run

`forge test -v`

Comment: But how does that fix the issue with `targetArtifact`?

Comment: AFAIK, the issue is not related to `targetArtifact`. It is about how forge imports and starts the invariant fuzzing. Without the proper import, the invariant feature is missing which results in failure to find contract to fuzz.

Comment: I am using `StdInvariant`. Did you have the same issue with `targetArtifact`? could you show an example that uses `targetArtifact` working?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue.

Debugging I found that the issue is having both a `targetArtifact` and a `targetContract`. Apprarently, this confused Foundry.

I debugged deploying the implementation contract and initializing manually (not testing with proxy) and then testing in the proxy with both `targetArtifact` and `targetContract` (FAIL) but when removing the `targetContract` it worked.

Thinking if implementing with a handler we would not have the need to specify the `targetArtifact` but just the target contract and the handler does the other work.

Hope this helps!